# Editable text inside UISegmentedController

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to have a UISegmentedController but the user can choose the segment and change the text inside. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks.

EDIT: This is what I would like to do. I have users which choose an option using UISegmentedControl. Under settings, I would like to give them the opportunity to modify what the texts in the UISegmentedControl is. I can use a UITextField and a button which triggers the change but I didn't like that solution. I considered putting a UISegmentedControl image with UITextField inside each segment but that does not seem like an elegant solution. Besides, I have no idea what the font is being used in UISegmentedControl. If I am not mistaken, by default, you can only fit a maximum of 12/13 chars or else it can break. iOS 5 SDK has some more methods to customize so it may be possible.

I coded a solution which involves a preview of what the UISegmentedControl will look like, 2 textfields to replace the texts inside each segment and a button which saves the value. I scraped it because I did not like the implementation and I just didn't like the execution too. I wanted the users to feel like they are using the UISegmentedControl and able to edit the texts inside it, up to a max of 12/13 chars.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit too broad.  What exactly do you need this for?  Because to edit text, the segment would have to have a responder chain element in it, so the keyboard would push it up the screen.  You could always just make a bunch of buttons.

Comment: Edit my question for more clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always dynamically change the values of the segmented controller in code. Would it be acceptable to have the user click the button, at which point you could pop up a form for the user to fill in with the new value, and then call this method on the segmented control:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment
```

Comment: I think this would work. It's the first solution I coded but I didn't like the implementation. I edited my original question. Thanks.